# WebView goback() method does not work

Tags: android

I have a requirement in my app where I need to render the multiple web pages in webview and provide the `goback()` method.

But unfortunately `goback()` method does not work in the case when we load the url(one of the url from multiple pages) which does not exit(Web page not available)and then we try to call the `goBack()`

Comment: provide code in question

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
         boolean isBack =false;
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            isBack = true;
        }
        else {
            // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
            super.onBackPressed();
            isBack = false;
        }
        return isBack;
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems you complicate your code you just try simple code below

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

this is simple code work fine for you,i dont know if you are using flag for other reasons.

Comment: its in fragment so I need to add that flag.

Comment: so you can try the solution given by  @KeLiuyue

Comment: my code is working fine for happy path but if one of my link does not work and if we get "Web page not available" then goBack() does not work

Comment: try [this](http://www.vetbossel.in/android-webview-webpage-not-available/) it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And you Web page not available,you can use `onReceivedError` method.

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

            if (request.isForMainFrame()) {
                //  you can do something when you Web page not available
                //  webView.goBack();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: My issue is that I am not able to goback () if one of my web page is not available

Comment: @Sam You can use the physical return key on the screen.And this can achieve it.And you can have a try.

Comment: My code is working fine for happy path but if one of my link does not work and if we get "Web page not available" then goBack() does not work